# c# Web Service validation and error handling. How do I implement this?

Tags: c#, web-services, exception

This is my first attempt at custom error handling so please let me know if I should do things different or change the way I've tried to go with this.  I'd like to apply this throughout the web service.  I've created a class that formats the soap exceptions within my web service for the client (throwClientException).  This seems to be working fine.  I've been having problems with the throw and catch part of the handling of the class.  From another class I'm  validating an employee ID.

If it comes back invalid I use:

```
ThrowSoapException tse = new ThrowSoapException();

throw tse.throwClientException(1, "EmployeeIDvalidation");
```

This seems to work.  The problem I'm running into is I'm not sure how to handle it when the code reached the catch of the main method.

I would like to use the:
    catch (SoapException se)
 and stop execution of the method to pass the generated soap exception to the client.  Please let me know what is the best way to handle what I'm trying to do.

```
public class ThrowSoapException : SoapException
{
        //    This XML Web service method generates a SOAP Client Fault code 
        public SoapException throwClientException(int faultCode, string nameOfActor)
        {
        string errorMessage = FaultCode(faultCode);
        string wsNamespace = "";
        string errSource = "customSOAPexception";          

        XmlQualifiedName tmpfaultCode = null;
        tmpfaultCode = SoapException.ClientFaultCode;

        XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
        XmlNode rootNode = xmlDoc.CreateNode(XmlNodeType.Element, SoapException.DetailElementName.Name, SoapException.DetailElementName.Namespace);
        XmlNode errorNode1 = xmlDoc.CreateNode(XmlNodeType.Element, "Errors", wsNamespace);
        XmlNode errorNode = xmlDoc.CreateNode(XmlNodeType.Element, "Error", wsNamespace);
        errorNode1.AppendChild(errorNode);

        XmlNode errNumberNode = xmlDoc.CreateNode(XmlNodeType.Element, "ErrorNumber", wsNamespace);
        errNumberNode.InnerText = faultCode.ToString();

        XmlNode errMsgeNode = xmlDoc.CreateNode(XmlNodeType.Element, "ErrorMessage", wsNamespace);
        errMsgeNode.InnerText = errorMessage;

        XmlNode errSourceNode = xmlDoc.CreateNode(XmlNodeType.Element, "ErrorSource", wsNamespace);
        errSourceNode.InnerText = errSource;

        errorNode.AppendChild(errNumberNode);
        errorNode.AppendChild(errMsgeNode);
        errorNode.AppendChild(errSourceNode);
        rootNode.AppendChild(errorNode1);

        //Constructing the exception
        SoapException soapEx = new SoapException(errorMessage, tmpfaultCode, nameOfActor, rootNode);

        return soapEx;
    }

    public string FaultCode(int faultCode)
    {
        switch (faultCode)                
        {
            case 1:
                return "Invalid Employee ID";
            case 2:
                return "blah blah";
            default:
                return "An error has occured.";
        }
    }
}
```

main method:

```
[WebMethod]
public string GetEligibility(int employeeID, . . . .)
{
       ....

       try
       { wsBase.SettingData(employeeID . . . . );}
       catch (SoapException se)
       { ??????  }

     //...more code
}
```

Comment: Interesting.  Well it appears that simply doing catch (SoapException )
       { throw;  } works.  Is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: I'm having a hell of a time trying to use this procedure to log the stack trace while hiding it from the client.  I can turn it to remote only but I dont think that will allow me to capture the stack trace when an error occurs.